# JQuerymobile redirect on pageshow with delay

Tags: redirect, jquery-mobile, delay

I am working on a JQuerymobile site with multiple pages. If one of the pages is shown (id="shown"), I want a redirect to another page (id=#redirected") after a delay of 6 seconds.

In my code, the commented line works for this, but the problem is that it even redirects to the #redirected page if the user changes to another sup page in the meantime. So what I would need would be an "if other page is not shown" thing in here.

I also tried with JQuery "changePage" (which would be good to handle transitions etc.), but I don't know how to implement a delay here.

Please see my code:

```
    $("#shown").bind("pageshow", function(e) {
    //window.setTimeout('window.location="#redirected"; ',6000);
    $.mobile.changePage("#fertig", { reverse: "false"});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a working jsfiddle for you:
http://jsfiddle.net/zUZMx/

Using the jQuery mobile multi-page template with three pages with ids "one", "two", and "three". When navigating to two it initiates a timeout of 6 seconds after which it checks if the active page is "two" and, if so, proceeds to redirect the user to three using mobile changePage (so you can make full use of transitions).

Javascript used:

```
$(document).delegate("#two", "pageshow", function(event) {
setTimeout(function() {
   if($.mobile.activePage.attr("id") == "two") {
        $.mobile.changePage("#three", {
            transition: "slide"
        });
    }
}, 6000);});​
```

If I understood your case correctly "two" would be changed to "shown" and "three" to "redirected".